# How to remove icon of a running program from system tray?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, notification-area

I have a program whose icon I need to completely remove from system tray.
I want the program to run in the background and to be able to bring it up with some defined hotkey.
All programs I found related to this problem only hide the program from visible area of system tray, but it doesn't remove it. When I extend status bar, the icon is there.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide the running program then there are several programs as below

1. [OuttaSight](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/download/did/1925/)
2. [WinRAP](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/download/did/1926/)
3. [Taskbar Hide](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/download/did/1927/)
4. [Tray It!](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/download/did/1928/)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you want to remove the icons?
Then try [this](http://www.pcworld.com/article/73163/remove_unwanted_icons_from_your_system_tray.html). (Yeah, it's from Windows 2000/98/95, but it's, with the exception of a few menu locations and graphical changes, the same)

If you'd just like to hide them , try [this](http://www.theeldergeek.com/notification_area.htm)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I tried really hard to find a solution for this. So for those looking for a way to completely hide icons from the system tray (and not just pushing them into the pop-up section), there’s a tool called PS Tray Factory. It’s old and it’s $25, but it’s the only tool I found that works on Windows 10.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP was asking about Windows XP not Windows 10.